# Multiline textview in table row not wrapping properly

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-tablelayout

I'm trying to get my text of my text view within the table row to appear on more than one line, but for some reason it doesn't wrap properly and I end up with this (see screenshot). I know the text view has something to do this it but I don't know what I causing this problem to occur. What can be done to resolve this issue?

**Screenshot**

[image]
[image]

**List item XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableRow>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: give some right padding and why you didn't set attributes for `<TableRow>`?

Comment: @Rustam Cool, but it doesn't work on tablets. Check appropriate screenshot.

Comment: Is it in landscape mode? if so then create separate layout for landscape in layout-land folder

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need specify `android:layout_weight="1"`.

> This value is telling to `TableRow` that the `TextView` is need to be equivalent to `match_parent`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableRow
            >
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="This is a long long long long text fodshfkjsdkjfjsh js hdfjksh kjdhf kjshdkjf"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I think if you use `weight`, the `layout_width` should be `0dp`.

Comment: In case you embed your views in a `LinearLayout` in the `TableRow` you need to set the `android:layout_weight="1"` on the `LinearLayout` only and on the `TextView` set `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

Answer (score 0):

give `<TableRow>` attributes

```
   <TableRow
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:paddingRight="10dip"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code may help

```
<com.project_name.JustifiedTextView.JustifiedTextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtHide"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:padding="25dp"
                    xmlns:noghteh="http://noghteh.ir" 
                    android:text="" 
                    android:textColor="@color/BlueText"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />
```

Link:
https://github.com/navabi/JustifiedTextView

Answer (score -1):

Simple fix would be to increase margin end,
try :

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```